# Train a new basecalling model for nanopore?

Tags: nanopore

Basecalling on nanopore requires a machine learning neural network model, for example [here](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12859-020-3459-0)

A popular software from Nanopore for it is https://github.com/nanoporetech/taiyaki, which has many people forking it.

However, the project requires an existing neural model to get started. I don't seem to be able to find a project for training a brand new model for Nanopore.